# How to properly fail in pytest pytest_sessionstart

Tags: python, pytest

I'm doing some verification in pytest's [`pytest_sessionstart`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) in `conftest.py` and if the verification fails I raise `ValueError`.

This works, but the printed error is pretty brutal with lots of `INTERNALERROR` lines that makes it confusing to read.

I was looking to something more clean with just my error message. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pytest.exit`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-exit):

```
import pytest


def precondition():
    raise ValueError('precondition failed')


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    try:
        precondition()
    except ValueError as err:
        pytest.exit(str(err), returncode=1)
```

Example output:

```
$ pytest
Exit: precondition failed
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! _pytest.outcomes.Exit: precondition failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```